# MobileConnect - Opt Out from specific keywords

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Within MobileConnect, how can keywords be used to manage opt-outs at a non-global level? I've reviewed the documentation for MobileConnect but I never found the information I was looking for.

Example: A single company has multiple brands operating within MobileConnect and want to reduce the overlap of opt-outs as much as possible. I know that when a contact replies STOP it will unsubscribe them from ALL keywords - but how can we present the option of only opting out from a single keyword?

Can we say "Text [Keyword] STOP to [Short/Long code] to end communication" and the system will know to only opt-out from that keyword, or is there more setup involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword level opt-out for SMS is not available yet.  I wondered what's the use of having multiple keywords for opt-outs in that case.  Figured out that this feature is only available in Australia.  Hopefully they enable it for everyone.

[Here's the idea for the same](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuVmQAK).  Please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a keyword data extension that controls your member's status. For example

Keyword DE: Phone, Locale, Status(boolean), keyword, DateAdded

Then you can put ampscript code in your SMS to update the status. For example, your opt in message will have ampscript to update this table with the member's phone, the related keyword and status=1. In your SMS for keyword opt out you will have the code to update the record with status=0 for that contact.

Based on this table you can do any segmentation for MobileConnect and JourneyBuilder.

Comment: How would you handle the opt out from the short/long code?

Comment: changing the status field in your data extension with ampscript from the sms.